# dd > a tag cause strange border *on Chrome* (Foundation Framework)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

**UPDATE: add `outline: 0;`**

---

I really tried looking for this issue on Google but can't get the right query to describe it.

I'm using Foundation Framework and when I add "Tabs" I get that strange border on click.

Here is the URL: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html

Here is an image showing the problem:

[image: Strange border]

It happens local & live on Foundation Doc's ***on Chrome***.
It does not happens on Firefox.

How do I disable it?

Edit: Here is my code:

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1">LINK</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel1">LINK</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Foundation Basic CSS.

Comment: post your code here...

Comment: `dd > a.active{border: none;}` will help you...???

Comment: C-link Nepal Same  issue :S
I updated for code

Comment: @ArieKatz: It is recommended to include the relevant code directly into the question, because linked pages can change. The idea of SO is to preserve valid questions and answers for other readers who run into the same problem.

Comment: @ArieKatz It is a requirement to provide code to reproduce the error on this site 1: To help people help you 2: To ensure that the question still has value if your link goes dead. At the end of the day the onus is on you to make the question clear and concise. May I suggest you take the CSS in my answer (minus the `outline: 0;` fix) that way whoever -1d you may reconsider.

Comment: you should accept the answer posted by @HiddenHobbes since you say it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `outline: 0;` to `.tabs dd > a`:

```css
.tabs dd, .tabs .tab-title {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.tabs dd > a, .tabs .tab-title > a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #222222;
    padding: 0.88889rem 1.77778rem;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 0.88889rem;
    outline: 0;
}
.tabs dd > a:hover, .tabs .tab-title > a:hover {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.tabs dd.active a, .tabs .tab-title.active a {
    background-color: white;
    color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs" data-tab="" role="tablist">
    <li class="tab-title" role="presentational"><a href="#panel1-1" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" controls="panel1-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title active" role="presentational"><a href="#panel1-2" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" controls="panel1-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title" role="presentational"><a href="#panel1-3" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" controls="panel1-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title" role="presentational"><a href="#panel1-4" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" controls="panel1-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do we need to do that though? Shouldn't Foundation take care of that. Isn't it supposed to be "battle tested"?

Comment: @JCraine No matter how thoroughly testing something is there will almost always be something that slips through the net, or perhaps Foundation like the effect in webkit browsers? ;)